# how to transform a folder of images into csv file?

Tags: csv

[image]I have a data set for segmentation project. The dataset have 2 folders containing train folder and annotated_train_data folder, both folders have images. input and label both are images. I want to make a csv file of this dataset to feed into a neural network. what is the easiest and efficient way to make csv file?

```
./images
./images/train
./images/train/label1.jpg
./images/train/label2.jpg
./images/train/label3.jpg
./images/annotated_train_data
./images/annotated_train_data/label1.jpg
./images/annotated_train_data/label2.jpg
./images/annotated_train_data/label3.jpg
```

Comment: How are labels stored in the form of images? Is the tree structure correct?

Comment: the labels are also images with same name as the input image itself but labels are stored in another folder

Comment: the label image is annotated version of the input image, and i am trying to use this dataset for segementation purpose.

Comment: what do you want in the output csv files? Only the path of each jpg file?

Comment: path of each file is also ok

Comment: yes only the path of each file in a column is also useful for me. for example. two columns of csv file have train images in one column and annotated_images in other column. but my question is how to generate the csv file using python?

Comment: I would strongly advise against transforming images into numerical values in a CSV. If you labels are binary masks, consider using them as PNG since that will save you disk space. Storibg jpgs into numerical values in CSV will make you loose compression and make a large and heavy csv yo transport, if you want to store both mask and image in a single file you could add the mask as a fourth layer to the image, it will also allow you to visualize images with transparence over the background which can be usefull for checking lab.

Answer (score 2):

```py
import os
import pandas as pd

BASE_DIR = 'images/'
train_folder = BASE_DIR+'train/'
train_annotation = BASE_DIR+'annotated_train_data/'

files_in_train = sorted(os.listdir(train_folder))
files_in_annotated = sorted(os.listdir(train_annotation))

images=[i for i in files_in_train if i in files_in_annotated]

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['images']=[train_folder+str(x) for x in images]
df['labels']=[train_annotation+str(x) for x in images]

pd.to_csv('files_path.csv', header=None)
```

Try this.

Comment: this code made me a list of all the images but how do i generate a csv file including all the images?

Comment: I have updated the path. This should solve your problem.